# Extra spaces between two button using GridLayout

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, grid-layout

Could someone please explain me the reason of the gap between the two radio buttons ? 
I even set the horizontal space to 0 but nothing has changed.

```
case composed:
new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
container.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
container.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, false));

for (int j = 0; j < this.itr; j++) {
    Button[] radioButton = new Button[answers.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++) {
            String ans = answers.get(i).getValue();
            radioButton[i] = new Button(container, SWT.RADIO);
            radioButton[i].setText(ans);

                }
                Text[] textField = new Text[answers.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++) {
                    textField[i] = new Text(container, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);

            for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++) {
                    textField[i] = new Text(container, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
                }
 }
```

I would appreciate any explanation or solution. 
[image: Screenshot of the wizard]

Comment: Maybe the "fixed size" string contains white spaces to the right? You could try to remove them with `trim()`.

Comment: I don't think so. All strings are pulled out from a json file and they have the same size.

Comment: Why there are 3 `new Label(container, SWT.NONE);` at the top? Are they used just as separators? But they should be 4 not 3, right? Maybe the first 1  has a different size...

Comment: Since the question is a label and I have 4 widget to show, then I had to add 3 empty labels as separators, to keep the 4 on the same row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the `Label` with the text `"Please enter the key size of your algorithm"` is on the first column of the `GridLayout`, therefore all the rows are affected by its size.

You should divide the two sections, for example using different `Composites` with different layouts, one for the first `Label` and another for the content with the buttons.

For example:

```
container.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

Composite questionContainer = new Composite(container, SWT.NONE);
questionContainer.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false));
questionContainer.setLayout(new FillLayout());

Label question = new Label(questionContainer, SWT.NONE);
question.setText("Please enter the key size of your algorithm");

Composite contentContainer = new Composite(container, SWT.NONE);
contentContainer.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false));
contentContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, false));

// rest of the content using contentContainer as parent
```

Comment: Instead of extra containers , you can also use a 2 column layout with a column span of 2 for the label.